# selecting from one database and inserting row to new database

Tags: vb.net, datatable, dataset, dataadapter

I'm looking for a pseudo code to write a VB.NET cursor to select columns from one table in one database and inserting it into another table in a different database (they are *not on the same server) using data adapter etc.
I just need something to refer to as I learn. Thanks

Dim selectStr As String = _
        "select * from  db1"

Dim insertStr As String = _
        "insert into db2(col1)"

```
    Try
        da_adapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(selectStr, connStr)
        da2_adapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(insertStr, connStr2)

        da_adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 720
        da_adapter.Fill(ds)

        da2_adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 720
        da2_adapter.Fill(ds)
Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

Comment: *select columns* or select data *in* certain columns?

Comment: If both databases are on the same server, why go through vb.net? Just do it directlybby using insert into... select

Comment: sorry typo, i meant to say not on the same server

Comment: I want to select data in certain columns

Answer (score 0):

In your original code, this part is wrong:

```
da2_adapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(insertStr, connStr2)
```

When you create a data adapter that way, the SQL statement you provide becomes part of the `SelectCommand`.  You want yours to be part of the `InsertCommand`, which you need to do yourself:

```
Dim cmd2 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(insertStr, connStr2)

da2_adapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
da2_adapter.InsertCommand = cmd2
```

Also, you need to set the `AcceptChangesDuringFill` property of the first data adapter to `False`.  That way, instead of setting the `RowState` of all the rows to `Unchanged` after populating the `DataTable`, they will remain as `Added` and ready to be inserted.

You then need to call `Update` on the second data adapter to save the data rather than calling `Fill`, which retrieves data.